# ACE Editor is not showing JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tabs, ace-editor

I am using ACE Editor on the top of jQuery tab. I am trying to fetch data of two files from server and trying to show on ACE Editor. I am using AJAX and JSON. two tabs are being created, things are going right for last file but all the data of files before last are disappeared. The wondering thing is when I am re-sizing the window suddenly ACE start showing data.
I know the things are very messy and I might be not clear, But can any body give me some clue.

Before showing data on ACE Editor I checked it using alert() and it is showing the correct data...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like editor is thinking it is hidden and doesn't draw anything, after showing hidden editor you should call `editor.resize()` to let it know that size of the container have changed.

Btw if you have many tabs, more than 2-3, it is better to use one editor and change sessions via `editor.setSession(..)`

Comment: difference between two tabs is that a div with class="ace_content" is not present for all the tabs having no data.

Comment: i am not sure i understand what your comment means. maybe you could show example of the page with this bug?